# I got a bug when set NavigationBar translucent

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

When I set `NavigationBar` to translucent, I expect that the `NavigationBar` will not has a shadow line under it, and `StatusBar` has the same background of the view's background [image: the result what I expect]

I code like this:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:YES];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"translucent_image"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
```

They work perfectly on 5.5 inch iPhone like iPhone6 Plus and iPhone 6s Plus, But when run on the smaller iPhones like iPhone 6s and iPhone 5s, I get a bug like problem, The `StatusBar` turn into black! They are the same code on iOS 8.2, iOS 8.3 and iOS 9.2, The only difference is the screen!  [image: black StatusBar when run on iPhone6s, iPhone 6 and iPhone 5s]

I try to change the `BarMetrics` from `UIBarMetricsDefault` to `UIBarMetricsCompact` or `UIBarMetricsDefaultPrompt` to fix this problem, finally the `StatusBar` work well but the shadow line come out in all iPhones!

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:YES];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"translucent_image"] forBarMetrics: UIBarMetricsCompact];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
```

[image: a shadow line come out]

so strange! is this a bug of iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your code to

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc]init] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

This works for me (i.e. I don't get the shadow)

Comment: so it is because the cause of the translucent image?

Comment: It appears to be because of the UIBarMetricsDefault. From the docs I can't figure out why there is a difference.